# Which Activity method is called after all the layout methods?

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to do something in an `Activity` after all the layout methods have been called, all the `View`s are in place and the `Activity` is ready to be displayed.

Which method can do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you are trying to get a width of a view or something. This should work

Add this to your activity's onCreate

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        // Put your code here. 

        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I never noticed the ViewTreeObserver API until your answer. This is perfect! :)

Comment: I got this from SO a longtime back from someone else's answer. :)

Comment: Same error, when it's called, the ActionBar is not inflated yet.

Comment: @blessenm can you please tell why you are not removing listner like this **vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)**, i have seen many post they are doing the same thing as you,but dont understand why??is their some logic behind??

Comment: @MuhammadBabar what u wrote should work fine. Copy pasted it from somewhere.

Comment: @blessenm **NO** blessenm i tried 'vto.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this)' and got exception,because the documentation says it is not gurantee that the reference of 'ViewTreeObserver' will live long thats why we have to again get the 'ViewTreeObserver' of the view and remove listener

Comment: What does layout refer to here?

Comment: @tyler-pfaff Any viewgroup layout in your activity. I mostly use the outermost layout of my activity.

Answer (score 1):

There's no magic method for that AFAIK. Suggest adding a `Handler` to your activity class, and `post()` a `Runnable` to it from `onCreate()` that contains the code you want to run.

If that's still too early you can `postDelayed()` instead.

Comment: Well, this works, but with post() it's not guaranted to call after all other operations, and with postDelayed there's a magic number on which I think the Activity will be able to finish inflating.

Comment: You may want to rethink what you are trying to do. If you *really* need to only run after layout() is called, subclass your top-level view and override onLayout(). (Remember to call super.onLayout() first).

Comment: Actually, this is a kind of hack to remove a Tab from the ActionBar.

Comment: IMHO your comment to override onLayout on top-level view much safer than your original answer, which could work fine 99.9% of the time, but then fail on some future user's device, due to no guarantee that it runs late enough!